# How to organize experimental data for A/B testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, beta-distribution

**Context:**

We have a fleet of aircraft in service, the manufacturer regularly produces upgrade recommendations (SB) to be implemented on aircraft in order to increase its reliability. Reliability is measured as the count of "events" due to technical malfunction divided by the number of flights over the same period.

**Data:**

We collect data on events (when, what, which aircraft...) in a database.
We also have a database with the list of upgrades (SB) and when they were installed on each aircraft.
By merging this two information we now have a table that tells us for every technical incident if the events happened PRE upgrade or POST upgrade.
From a third table we're able to get the amount flights to compute the reliability.

**Questions**

1. For each of this upgrade (SB), I want to assess whether there was a significant change in reliability, but I don't know how to organize the data.
   Since we're comparing rate (events / flights) for each SB I compute :

- Rate PRE SB
- Rate POST SB

But to my knowledge, most statistical test requires variance input, but since this measure are already aggregate I'm stuck.
So what who be the right approach there ?

2. Instead of comparing events rate, would that make more sense to assume a Poisson distribution for the events distribution and compare whether the two distribution differ POST and PRE SB ?

**EDIT**

By considering a binomial distribution for the events, with a probability of success of "event rate", it seems to be similar to the [Amazon reseller](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2011/09/27/bayesian-amazon/) issue. For which the Beta distribution is used.

Here's an illustration of how I used it to assess the significance of an upgrade on reliability.

H0: event rate PRE = events rate Post

Each of this table represent an upgrade (SB), with the 3 parameters required to compute the Beta probability:

- **s**: number of events (success)
- **f**: number of failure (# of flights - success)
- **p**: event rate (probability of success)

On the diagonal (grey) I've computed the P(p_pre > p | s_pre, f_pre), so the probability of p_pre being greater than "p" from a sample with "s" and "f". (informative but useless for the task at hand).

On the two other quadrant I've computed P(p_post > p| s_pre, f_pre) and
P(p_pre > p| s_post, f_post), or the probability of the real event rate being greater than "p_pre" with a sample containing "s_post" success and "f_post failure".

[image]

We would consider the difference in events rate significant if the value in both quadrant is greater than 100 - p_value or p_value. (Since the reliability can improve or deteriorate after upgrade, value outside this boundary would be consider unlikely).

Does that look like a legitimate methodology ?

Thank you

Comment: I wonder if each incident has a reliability value that is ranked and correlated for same symptom or different.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 each incident is relate to a specific sub system (ATA). And SB also target ATA. I just don't know how to group them to obtain some measure of rate and variance. Maybe considering the rate / aircraft (PRE and POST) could work but then the fleet reliability does not equal the average of aircraft reliability.

Comment: I guess you use % of planned availability time vs maintenance time to indicate an improvement in reliability or maintenance. and % of reliable flight time, number of unforced errors. Also variance with mean comes confidence level and with expected criteria for pass/fail also comes the likelihood of success.

Comment: so for a binomial distribution the variance is related to the rate. so you don't need to measure the variance

Comment: @seanv507 indeed, after some research it seems my problem relate to the issue of assessing "Probability of Probability". As illustrated in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8idr1WZ1A7Q
We read the "event rate" as the probability of a Binomial distribution representing the odds of an aircraft having an events. Then my problem is about assessing the probability distribution of that probability PRE and POST upgrade. It seems to be related to the beta function but I haven't found a straight explanation yet.

Comment: no you just need a binomial test. see https://byrony.github.io/understanding-ab-testing-and-statistics-behind.html. if you have a total failures/successes > 5 ( or 10 -rule of thumb) you can do a z test, and then see this difference in proportions test.   For a small

Comment: @seanv507 thanks ! That's a good point, when using t-test to compare two groups (PRE vs POST) there're usually 2 assumptions that are important though: 
homogeneity of variance and random sampling. In my case the sampling is not random as the PRE and POST events are sampled chronologically and the sample size can be quite different (ie: different variance in a Normal approximation).
That's why I the Beta dist. seemed to be a better approach but I'd give your suggestion a try.